# read from a stream response and write it to another response Node js

Tags: node.js, request, request-promise

I got this in the principal handler:

```
app.get('/static', (request, response) => {

const id=request.query.id;
const url=endpoint+id;

request({url:url, resolveWithFullResponse: true})
 .then(result => {
 //"result" is a stream response,I want all data from here goes to "response"
 //"result -> "response"
})
```

The streamer code is:

```
app.get('/getfile', (request, response) =>{
//get the client somewhere
    client.createReadStream()
        }).then(stream => {
            stream.on('end', () => {
                response.end();
            });
            stream.on('error', (error) => {
                response.end();
            });
            stream.pipe(response);
        })
})
```

I want all the result from from "result" goes to "response"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If result is a stream, you can simply use pipe with response, do not forget to add proper filename and contentType:

```
request({url:url})
 .then(result => {
   const filename = 'data.json';
   const contentType = 'application/json'
   res.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename*=${filename}`); // set a filename for your response f.e. data.json
   res.set(Content-Type', contentType); // set a content type f.e. application/json
   result.pipe(response);
})
```

note: if attach to arbitrary binary file , use `Content-Type=application/octet-stream`

Comment: it's not for download a file, it's for displaying an image in <img> tag, so 'Content-disposition' should be "inline"

Comment: Do you render a page or is it some AJAX call from React/Angular/Vue/Whatever? Because in this case is better approach to send a URL of img if you have it stored on server. Maybe you should provide more info

Comment: no, the images are not in a public host, that is why I don't put it directly

Comment: pretty sure it works? I got Content-Length: 0, not data is being trasmited

Comment: can you provide some example code to github (or somehwere else)?

Comment: Streamer code looks good but I think i dont fully understand what you want to do. Maybe try to describe your workflow and provide more info about endpoint. Is it express btw?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196758/discussion-between-john-balvin-arias-and-l2ysho).